# How to put commas in this sentence?

Tags: conjunctions, commas

Where should commas go (if any) in the following sentence?

> 1)   Start practicing now so when you get famous you don't have to hire a hundred people to get upset for you.

I have an intuitive preference that it should be commented like this:

> 1)   Start practicing now so when you get famous, you don't have to hire a hundred people to get upset for you.

The following is the entire context of this sentence with the target sentence in **bold text**.

> **Practice for Fame and Fortune by Ignoring Negativity.**
>
> Think of negativity as a great, fun opportunity to ready yourself for a life of fame. Famous people have to ignore vast amounts of negativity about them. If they didn't, they would forever be wasting their time apologizing, defending theirselves, or crying foul to people in charge.
>
> Do you find yourself getting worked up over one little comment? Think about it this way: Even if they wanted to, a famous person couldn't read all the bad things about them. They would have to hire an entire, full-time staff of a hundred people to read, get upset, and respond to all the stuff written about them. **Start practicing now so when you get famous, you don't have to hire a hundred people to get upset for you.**
>
> The key is really to think of negativity as just "part of the game". Like Tetris, The Legend of Zelda, or PAC-MAN. You just step around it. Keep moving ahead. Don't look back at that thing you stepped around. Stop that. Stop lookihg back. Are you looking back? POW you lost the level because you were looking back. Did you learn? Stop looking back at "that thing" you stepped around.

Comment: Me, I'd put the comma after *now*, which divides the sentence into injunction/justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma where you place it does make the sentence easier to read, but I don't think that it's absolutely required. Your instincts are good though, since it's clearer with the comma, and the comma isn't wrong, keep it! :)

Comment: I've added the full context to help you understand "for you". :)

Comment: If you revise your answer to eliminate the reference to the lack of context and include the content of your comment I'll upvote it :)

Comment: Commas are always required in the place that he put it.

Comment: @BryantDonner I'd like to see a credible reference on that.

Answer (score 1):

Start practicing **now,** so when you get famous, you don't have to hire a hundred people to get upset for you.

Comment: In my opinion, even though that's possible, and maybe even prescriptively correct, it's too choppy for the comedic flow.

Comment: For speech, you're right. I'm not exactly sure about writing, however.